# MVC where should algorithms go?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am writing an app that writes some info specified by the user into some files specified by the user.

I want to use MVC pattern. I need some direction.

I can't figure out how to separate Logic from Ui.

I have some complex algorithms to perform on data(files provided by the user).

I think I need some module where these algs are stored and I just pass references to data, on which alg are performed. But MVC provides no such storage ~ or I don't know where to put it. 
Please help me separate whatever is needed to be separated.
Should model store data and provide interface to access that data? Do I understand it right?

**MAYBE I do not need MVC here?**

So far I have come up with such a model:

**Is it GOOD?**
[image]

Comment: _"I want to use MVC pattern. I need some direction."_ well, in order to use a pattern, you need to master a bunch of them, and pick one for a specific reason, and not just for the sake of. If you state then "I can't figure out how to separate Logic from Ui", there is a chance you should have a deeper reading about the topic ; ))

Comment: Well please suggest then some good books where I can read about it. I believe I need MVC here but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Is it a web or a desktop application? Based on that, you can google for any good resources.

Comment: desktop app. I tries googling. did not help.

Comment: I learnt MVC via Cocoa/iOS stuff [for `OS X` / `iPhone`] fyi, and it was pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should algorithms go in MVC?

Put them in the Model.

> MAYBE I do not need MVC here?

Almost no pattern is mandatory in any one scenario, but if you have a UI then MVC is probably a good idea.